# How do I call the iScroll refresh methode in a parent react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iscroll

I am struggling currenlty with iScroll in combination with reactJS.
This code samples are written in typescript.

I created a wrapper class for iScroll:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var iScroll = require('iscroll');        
...

    componentDidMount() {
            this._initializeIScrollInstance();
            console.log(this);
        }

    _initializeIScrollInstance() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                let element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
                const iScrollInstance = new iScroll(element, this.props.options);
                this._iScrollInstance = iScrollInstance;
            }, 100);
        }

    render() {
                return (
                    <div style={ this.props.style } >
                        { this.props.children }
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
```

Then I use it like this in my sidebar class for instance.

```
<ScrollWrapper>
 <SidebarMenu toggle={ this.toggle.bind(this) } />
</ScrollWrapper>
```

The problem I am facing is when I toggle a menu inside my sidebar. This means the height changes so I need to call the refresh methode for iScroll.
But how can I achieve this?
Can I get the _iScrollInstance in my parent component?

Its possible to keep a state inside my sidebar and pass it down to the ScrollWrapper as a property and watch for it in componentReceiveProps. 
But this sounds like a cheap solution to me.
Anyone maybe have a better solution for that kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code :

```
<ScrollWrapper>
 <SidebarMenu toggle={ this.toggle.bind(this) } />
</ScrollWrapper>
```

I see the child component action (toggle) needs to do something with the parent component (scroll). The idiomatic way to do this is for the parent to give the child component a function (callback) that the child calls when it wants something in the parent to change.

Note: The recommeded way is to use `flux` ... but thats a whole other topic (lookup redux which is what I use).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I thought about the way with a callback function too but I had no idea how to pass it down within my wrapper. I took now the way with redux and it works perfect. Are there any advantages with redux over normal facebook flux?

Comment: Its very easy to use. And works well with TypeScript too : https://github.com/basarat/tsb/blob/master/docs/contributing/REDUX.md